# Step by step guide to setup bugzilla for shared hosting

Tags: shared-hosting, bugzilla

I am using [bluehost](http://bluehost.com/) shared hosting. I want to setup bugzilla. There are lot of guides on google search. As i having a tons of stuff on bluehost. I am looking for a trustable source. Anybody who is having step by step guide to install bugzilla. I have shell access.

PS:-- for precautions i have a backup. But i dont want to mess up the things.

**EDIT**

I was trying:--

Stuck here:--

I was just going with the flow:--

1. ./checksetup.pl
2. /ramdisk/bin/perl install-module.pl --all
3. vi ./localconfig (modified db, dbuser, dbuserpass)
4. ./checksetup.pl

and after that by script :--

- Tables created
- some directories, css files and atlast

  ```
  Creating ./lib/.htaccess...
  Creating ./template/.htaccess... 
  Creating .htaccess...
  Creating contrib/.htaccess...
  Creating t/.htaccess...
  There is no such group: apache. Check your $webservergroup setting in
  ./localconfig.
  ```

Back on terminal.. What next??? I think it should ask me about administrative username and password etc

Comment: Please dont ask for step-by-step guides. It shows that you are not willing to learn anything. And, quite honestly, we're not a support department who writes documentation.

Comment: @pauska please check the question. I have specified what i did. Please check first and then say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For bluehost u need to make that entry blank

means in bugzilla/localconfig

```
 $webservergroup="apache"
```

change it to

```
   $webservergroup=""
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message specifies clearly what the problem is. In your localconfig file, there is a setting for the value $webservergroup (which is the Unix group your webserver runs with the permissions of). You have it set to "apache" (which, I believe, is the default) but there is no group in the system with that name. So you need to set it to the true name of the group your webserver runs as.

I am not familiar with bluehost but another common value is "www-data". To find out, do `ps aux | grep apache` and look at the first column. One may be root, but the next few will be the value you want.

Gerv

Comment: thnks.. for bluehost u need to make that entry blank.. thanks for ur help

Comment: The comment in the localconfig file warns against setting the value to "", as it can be a security risk. Some files are made world readable/writeable, and so (depending on how bluehost works - does it give out accounts, or entire VMs?) other bluehost users on the same machine may be able to change your files.